# python: best way to work with time schedule intervals: in or between

Tags: python, time, setinterval

I am getting from DB json field with time schedule in the form of:

```
{'monday': '10:00-22:00', 'tuesday': '10:00-22:00', 'wednesday': '10:00-22:00', 'thursday': '10:00-22:00', 'friday': '10:00-22:00', 'saturday': '10:00-22:00', 'sunday': '10:00-22:00'}
```

truly believe, there is simple way to check if current time in the interval and get back the result TRUE or FALSE according to the schedule.
even if i get time for the day of the week: 10:00-22:00, is there a way to check if 13:37 "isin" the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datetime objects.

```
import datetime

DATA = {'monday': '10:00-22:00', 'tuesday': '10:00-22:00', 'wednesday': '10:00-22:00', 'thursday': '10:00-22:00', 'friday': '10:00-22:00', 'saturday': '10:00-22:00', 'sunday': '10:00-22:00'}


def is_in_time_frame(day, time):
    time_frame = DATA[day]
    start, end = map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M").time(),
                     time_frame.split('-'))
    return start <= time <= end


print(is_in_time_frame('monday', datetime.time(hour=9, minute=0)))
print(is_in_time_frame('monday', datetime.time(hour=11, minute=0)))
```

If you are going to use this a lot, you can implement a class TimeInterval as follows:

```
import datetime

DATA = {'monday': '10:00-22:00', 'tuesday': '10:00-22:00', 'wednesday': '10:00-22:00', 'thursday': '10:00-22:00',
        'friday': '10:00-22:00', 'saturday': '10:00-22:00', 'sunday': '10:00-22:00'}


class TimeInterval:
    def __init__(self, start: datetime.time, end: datetime.time):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end

    def __contains__(self, item: datetime.time):
        return self.start <= item <= self.end


def is_in_time_frame(day, time):
    time_frame = TimeInterval(*map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M").time(),
                                   DATA[day].split('-')))
    return time in time_frame


print(is_in_time_frame('monday', datetime.time(hour=9, minute=0)))
print(is_in_time_frame('monday', datetime.time(hour=11, minute=0)))
```

Comment: Thank you, that what i did with in my code. But I thought, there should be "nice looking" way, like : time isin interval. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: you could have a "nicer" way by creating your own class TimeInterval, which stores time start, time end, and implements `in` and whatever else you need.